# get current time?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

How do you get the current time in VC++ CLI Visual Studio 2008,

Answer (score 5):

```
System::DateTime now = System::DateTime::Now;
```

(`System::DateTime::UtcNow` is another alternative)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .NET [System.DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) property to get the current time.  You can then use the standard [DateTime members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_members.aspx) to get at specific information.

For example:

```
System::DateTime^ now = System::DateTime::Now;
Console::WriteLine(L"Current hour: {0}", now->Hour);
```

Comment: DateTime is a value type - you don't need to use the tracking pointer operator (^)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Mistook CLI to mean command-line interface, rather than Common Language Infrastructure. Move along, nothing to see here.

---

This should be fairly cross-platform:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void main( )
{
     char dateStr [9];
     char timeStr [9];
     _strdate( dateStr);
     printf( "The current date is %s \n", dateStr);
    _strtime( timeStr );
    printf( "The current time is %s \n", timeStr);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want a windows specific method:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    printf("Year:%d\nMonth:%d\nDate:%d\nHour:%d\nMin:%d\nSecond:% d\n" ,st.wYear,st.wMonth,st.wDay,st.wHour,st.wMinute,st.wSecond);
}
```

[Source](http://www.codersource.net/c/c-tutorials/c-date-and-time.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use the time function from time.h
[definition and example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/)